# Req.body from post returns as undefined no matter how I send it

Tags: ajax, express

This question has been asked but none of the answers help me figure this out.  I'm passing a variable through ajax like so:

```
    var myData = "Hi Og";

    $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: myData,
  url: 'https://example.com:8443',
  success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
  }
});
```

In my express server I have this in my server.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('certificates/key.pem', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('certificates/cert.pem', 'utf8');

var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies

// your express configuration here

var httpServer = http.createServer(app);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

// For http
httpServer.listen(8080);
// For https
httpsServer.listen(8443);

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.myData);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header('Content-type', 'text/html');
    return res.end('<h1>Hello, Secure World!</h1>');
});
```

With the above code I get a response back at the originating sender with the alert "Hello, Secure World!".  However in the console I get "undefined".
I changed the content-type to application/json but that gave me a 500 error.  I changed req.body.data and same thing undefined.  `req.body gives me this = {}`

Comment: Your request body isn't JSON, nor does your request state to the server that it is sending JSON.

Comment: Thank you, were would I put that it's json?  @robertklep

Comment: You tried changing the content-type to `application/json` and got a 500 error. That 500 error has a reason (and quite possibly, it would have logged that reason). Or don't use JSON, and use [`bodyParser.urlencoded()`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions).

Comment: Is the content-type the reason that I'm getting the undefined?  @robertklep

Comment: The reason you're getting undefined is because the Express server expects JSON (and _only_ JSON), but you're not _sending_ JSON (or, at least, telling the server that what you are sending is JSON). The latter you do with by setting the content type header.

Comment: I set res.header('Content-type', 'application/json');  then in the ajax call I set   data: JSON.stringify({name: "test"}),
  contentType: 'application/json', now I get a CORS error.  I read up the mozilla documentation on the CORDS.  shouldn't this work? It sending json and telling it to receive json? @robertklep

Comment: CORS is a different problem: you are sending a cross-domain request, which is only allowed in certain specific situations _or_ when your Express server is allowing those requests to be made (for instance, using the [`cors`](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) middleware).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @robertklep direction I needed to property parse the body of the data with `app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded() );`
I incorrectly had this as json which was causing it to be undefined.